# Domain Mapping subsites of an Add-on Mulsite Domain

Tags: multisite, domain-mapping

Consider we have a hosting account registered with a domain abc.com.

Now we installed a Wordpress Multisite domain at xyz.com (xyz is a subfolder in the public_html folder, where xyz.com is acting as an add-on domain in abc.com's hosting account.)

We made sure that all the steps are followed and are sure that multisite is functioning properly by testing it at child/blog site 123.xyz.com)

Now, in order to perform domain mapping, we used domain mapping plugin. However, I'm confused and do not know how to park a domain and then map it a subdomain of an add-on multisite domain.

For example, mapping 123.xyz.com to 123.com doesn't work because I parked the domain 123.com at domain root "/public_html" where the original multisite root is "/public_html/xyz.com" Doing so, the parked domain 123.com is showing the content of our main domain abc.com but not our 123.xyz.com

Please provide me a solution.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the answer.

When we use a subdomain (xyz.com) on the cpanel and create a wordpress multisite on it, we need to simply assign 123.com add-on domain in the cpanel and change the domain root to the same root of xyz.com. For example, if domain root of xyz.com is /public/xyz.com, then when we add 123.com, we need to use the same domain root /public/xyz.com also for 123.com.

Using same domain root as that of the main site in Cpanel, we can access 123.com as mapped domain for 123.xyz.com wordpress multisite.